# How can I make 'emacsclient' open in native fullscreen every time I launch it from the terminal in macOS?

Tags: emacs, fullscreen

> MacOS 14 Sonoma
> emacs-plus / doomemacs

I use `emacsclient -c` to launch Emacs from the terminal. It opens in a small window with no focus. It is a waste to manually set fullscreen.

I want Emacs to open in fullscreen mode with input focus, handsfree. Also, I prefer native fullscreen because non-native fullscreen blocks other windows, which I dislike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following lines in your configuration file (`~/.config/doom/config.el` for `doomemacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`):

```
(setq ns-use-native-fullscreen :true)
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . fullscreen))
```

Save (`C-x C-s`) the configuration and exit emacs. The next time you launch Emacs, it will open in native fullscreen mode with input focus.